# HTML messed up in just one Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, mailchimp

I've got an issue with Outlook. I have a newsletter created in Mailchimp, custom coded, which looks good in all email clients, including Outlook, except for just one person where the code is all over the place. I'm talking specifically about this bit of code:

```
 <table border="0" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" style="width:600px;max-width:600px;overflow:hidden;">
    <tr>
      <td class="header" align="left" valign="bottom" style="padding-bottom:0;">
        <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ce2871176f2cf0da723a750b1/images/026f82b3-11d7-4499-a7a9-fedc75467f5c.png" style="width:100%;" class="align-header">
        <!--[if mso]>   
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="container-padding content" align="center" valign="bottom" style="padding-left:24px;padding-right:24px;padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:12px;background-color:#0ea19b;">
        <![endif]-->
        <div class="container-padding content" valign="bottom" align="center" style="padding-left:24px;padding-right:24px;padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:12px;background-color:#0ea19b;margin-top:0!important; display:inline-block;width:95%;">
                        <!--[if mso]>
            <table border="0" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" style="width:500px;max-width:500px;"><tr><td width="200">
            <![endif]-->
            <div class="title" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:18px;font-weight:600;color:#fff;text-align:left;">July 2015</div>
            <!--[if mso]>
                </td><td width="300" valign="middle">
                <![endif]-->
                <div class="title2" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:600;color:#fff;text-align:right;"><a href="http://kent.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=ce2871176f2cf0da723a750b1&id=b8f569ff81" target="_blank">Subscribe to our<br>consumer newsletter</a></div><br>
                <!--[if mso]>
                </td></tr></table>
                <![endif]-->
                <div class="social" style="display:block;width:100%;text-align:center;float:left;">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Kent-Trading-Standards/386603161497200" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ce2871176f2cf0da723a750b1/images/7f528f2d-ce24-4fd7-a961-8e70c32aa87d.png" border="0">
            </a>&nbsp;
            <a href="https://twitter.com/kent_ts" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ce2871176f2cf0da723a750b1/images/250357af-fa8d-447d-ae24-e5836c66c0b1.png" border="0">
            </a>&nbsp;
            <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/kentts/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ce2871176f2cf0da723a750b1/images/87851a7e-7f3d-49e0-8fc0-3bf8bb12b98f.png" border="0">
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ce2871176f2cf0da723a750b1/images/559f5753-373f-47f7-a97e-ffe454a991d8.jpg" style="width:100%;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="container-padding content" align="left" style="background-color:#ffffff">
```

Is there any particular setting in Outlook that will cause this? Everywhere else it looks good, except for one single laptop. I'm going mad here trying to figure it out.
Thank you!

Comment: Cannot under the issue exactly..can you please provide the Whole code..

Comment: What's different about this one laptop? Is it the same version of Outlook? are they connected to Exchange, POP3 or IMAP? Has the user set to read all internet email in plain text?

Comment: Same laptop, same version of Outlook (2010), set up by IT department in the same way as everyone else's. That's why is driving me crazy. The user might have fiddled with some settings that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook's display is based off the DPI settings in Windows, which is likely why it is only affecting the one person. This can greatly increase the size of your images as well as your tables, etc causing havoc on your layout.  This is a client-side feature (usually on HD laptops as by default they are usually set to 125% DPI) and nothing that you can really do to control it on your end as designer/sender.

If you have that person make sure the DPI setting is on 100%, that should solve the issue - but as you can't tell that to ALL of your audience all of the time, it may be better to put preventative code in the email instead and design with this in mind.

1. Set inline px definitions (or you can use conditional defined tables  surrounding your code) of your your tables and tds.
2. Use mso-padding-alt and mso-cellspacing.
3. Use this for PNG images:

   `<!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <xml>
     <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
       <o:AllowPNG/>
       <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
   </xml>
   <![endif]-->`
4. Insert this in the HTML tag:

   `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">`

Best resource I have found for tips on Outlook's DPI issue is on [J.M. White's blog](https://blog.jmwhite.co.uk/2014/03/28/solving-dpi-scaling-issues-with-html-email-in-outlook/). Below are some references from Litmus and Email on Acid as well.

[Litmus](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/151-mystery-solved-dpi-scaling-in-outlook-2007-2013)

[Email On Acid](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/dpi_scaling_in_outlook_2007-2013)

Comment: Thank you! Believe it or not, I was just reading the same page on Litmus. Looks like the mystery might be solved after all. I'll give it a go and see what's happening. I HATE OUTLOOK!

Comment: Outlook requires a mindset beyond regular HTML email development. Basically design and development for Outlook is like a whole new specialization. If you are looking to concentrate on an Outlook audience, I would research the capabilities of the conditional code as well as VML.  Two great references as well for help with buttons or backgrounds is backgrounds.cm and buttons.cm. If you feel my answer was a solution, please make sure to mark it as such. Thanks and good luck

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't Like HTML but there is a fix for this.

> On the extreme end, you can send plain text email. Even without going that far, you can send HTML email, as long as you keep your
>   formatting simple: as a rule, don't use any CSS elements (if you're
>   not sure what those are, either ask your web designer or simply don't
>   worry about it).
>
> If you keep things simple, Outlook users shouldn't notice anything out
>   of the ordinary.
>
> Alternately, you can simply accept that Outlook users may have
>   trouble, and provide them with a link to view your email as a web
>   page. This allows you to use HTML email templates and other advanced
>   styling features, while still giving users of mail clients that don't
>   support those features an option to see your messages as they were
>   meant to be seen.

Reference: https://help.aweber.com/hc/en-us/articles/204030726-Why-Doesn-t-My-HTML-Message-Display-Correctly-in-Outlook-

Comment: It does work and it looks good on all Outlook clients I've seen, except for one. It's nothing wrong with the code as it renders exactly as it should. I'm guessing that the particular one Outlook client have some sort of setting out of place (if there is such a thing).

Comment: Have you check if they are allowing html code to be run in outlook?

Comment: Yes, HTML is allowed to run.

Comment: What is the version of the client?

Comment: Outlook 2010, same as everyone else.